# Почему не получаетеся с интернационализацией модуля?

Tags: yii2

вот так подключаю в модуле

```
namespace sirgalas\menu;
class Module extends \yii\base\Module
{
    public function registerTranslations()
    {
        Yii::$app->i18n->translations['modules/users/*'] = [
            'class'          => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
            'sourceLanguage' => 'ru-Ru',
            'basePath'       => 'sirgalas/menu/messages',
        ];
    }
    public static function t($category, $message, $params = [], $language = null)
    {
        return Yii::t($category, $message, $params, $language);
    }
```

файл находится в папке `massages/ru-RU/` директории модуля в модуле подключаю его название `translit.php`

в представлении подключаю так
`<?= Module::t('translit','Menu setup'); ?>` получаю `'Menu setup'` почему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в моем случае надо было поступить так

```
public function registerTranslations()
    {
        Yii::$app->i18n->translations['translit'] = [
            'class'          => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
            'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US',
            'basePath'       => '@vendor/sirgalas/yii2-wordperss-menu/messages',
        ];
    }
```

, а потом вызывать все через `Module::t('translit','Menu create')` то есть должно было совпадать 'translit' вот здесь `Yii::$app->i18n->translations['translit']` и вот здесь `Module::t('translit','Menu create')` да и не забыть указать адрес полный с `vendor` `@vendor/sirgalas/yii2-wordperss-menu/messages',`